# razor select box cannot convert lambda expression

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I need to convert this `<select id="degreemultiselect" multiple="multiple"></select` to a razor control `@Html.DropDownList` but I am getting the error message it says "cannot convert lambda expression to type string?" is that because of the model being a list `public List<DegreeModel> selectedRequesterDegrees { get; set; }` is there a work around for this?

```
@Html.DropDownList(x => x.selectedRequesterDegrees, new { id = "degreemultiselect", @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedRequesterDegrees)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public List<DegreeModel> selectedRequesterDegrees { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Test
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedRequesterDegrees, new SelectList(Model.selectedRequesterDegrees, "Id", "Name"), null, new { id = "degreemultiselect", @class = "form-control" })
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Test()
    {
        selectedRequesterDegrees = new List<DegreeModel>()
        {
            new DegreeModel(){ Id=1,Name="aa"},
            new DegreeModel(){ Id=2,Name="bb"},
            new DegreeModel(){ Id=3,Name="cc"}
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Result:

[image]